# Sidebar menu treeview not opening when active through dynamically

Tags: jquery, user-interface, sidebar, submenu, kendo-treeview

I am having some problem while activating the side menu tree in my page.
My JQuery code is:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    alert("hi");
    $("#home a:contains('Home')").parent().addClass('active');
     $("#report a:contains('Report Format')").parent().addClass('active');


if ($("#report a:contains('Report Format')").parent().hasClass('active')) {
$("#dropdown_menu  a:contains('Summary')").parent().addClass('active');
}

});
```

Here is my html code for home page:

```
<body id="home">
<nav class="navbar-default navbar-static-side" role="navigation">
            <div class="sidebar-collapse">
                <ul class="nav metismenu" id="side-menu">
                    <li class="nav-header">
                        <div class="dropdown profile-element"> <span>
                            <img alt="image" class="img-circle" src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/img/profile_small.jpg" />
                             </span>
                            <a data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle" href="#">
                            <span class="clear"> <span class="block m-t-xs"> <strong class="font-bold">Anilkumar</strong>
                             </span> <span class="text-muted text-xs block">Admin<b class="caret"></b></span> </span> </a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu animated fadeInRight m-t-xs">
                                <li><a href="#">Profile</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Contacts</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Mailbox</a></li>
                                <li class="divider"></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Logout</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        <div class="logo-element">
                            IN+
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/home/homePage"><!-- <i class="fa fa-th-large"></i> --> <span class="nav-label">Home</span> <!-- <span class="fa arrow"></span> --></a>

                    </li>

                    <li id="dropdown_menu">
                        <a href="#"><!-- <i class="fa fa-th-large"></i> --> <span class="nav-label">Summary</span> <span class="fa arrow"></span></a>
                        <ul class="nav nav-second-level">
                            <li ><a href="#">Dashboard</a></li>
                             <li ><a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/home/reportFormat">Report Format</a></li>

                        </ul>
                    </li>


                       </ul>
                       </div>
                       </nav>
</body>
```

**And Another Report page is also same as above.**

I am also attaching a screenshot of my expected output and actual output
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OTLAA.png).

Please check the screenshot.
Any response would be appreciated.

Comment: requires some html to make sense as there's currently no correlation between your jquery and the labels in your screenshot

Comment: Here's a fiddle, https://jsfiddle.net/manoeuvres/re4tnesn/ I can't say if it helps your case as I don't have the CSS and your output image doesn't relate to your html - or your js. I can only say in this case your js is ineffective as there isn't a `#report` id attribute in your html to target

Comment: Hello @Sam0, I have added the css and jquery links include in fiddle, https://jsfiddle.net/anililu20/re4tnesn/1/  please check

Comment: Still the same situation. You jQuery is looking for the div called `#report` so it can find the `a` tag with the text content: `Report Format` and then go back up the tree to find the parent of the `a` tag to give it the `active` class thus allowing it to open.

However, there isn't a tag within your html with an id called `#report` for it to find, hence undesired response. Therefore find the `li` tag you wish to be opened and apply the `#report` id. From here it's a case of understanding which level of parent to wish to label as `active`